# Drop-out pulse test

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, switching, pulse

I have a switching MOSFET circuit.

Input to the switching MOSFET circuit is 11V at the drain. 
The gate is connected to a function generator. 5V peak-peak, frequency = 1kHz, 1ms (time period) & 90% duty cycle.

MOSFET Circuit (MOSFET IC Part Number : [VN7140AJ)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vn7140aj.pdf) :

[image]

Probing at the gate & source (drain is at 11V,) I get the below waveform (only with the MOSFET) :

[image]

THE ABOVE WAVEFORM IS OBTAINED WITHOUT CONNECTING THE MOSFET SOURCE TO THE DOWNWARD CIRCUIT. ONLY 11V, FG INPUT is provided and the Output is taken at the source.

With the same MOSFET circuit, if I connect this circuit source terminal to the my new circuit (shown below,)

[image]

I get the below waveform:

[image]

Why doesn't the MOSFET source go to 0V after I connect to the new circuit? But it goes to 0V, if I don't connect to the new circuit.

It doesn't go to 0V, because of C0101 & C0102 capacitors,  or what might be the reason?

Comment: There is no MOSFET in your schematic.  Please consider posting the part of the circuit you are asking about.

Comment: Yes sorry. The drain is connected to the Power Supply of 11V. Gate is connected to the FG with the mentioned parameters and the source is connected to the NEW circuit as shown in the diagram. Please imagine the MOSFET as I have mentioned in this comment

Comment: Please imagine how much better the responses would be if we could see your schematic.  This is Electrical Engineering - schematics are kinda a thing with us.

Comment: Hi. Sorry. Added the MOSFET Circuit and mentioned the part number as well. Please excuse for the poor drawing of the MOSFET circuit. Can you please provide me an answer

Comment: Edited the question. Please remove the downvote

Comment: What is '+BAT' connected to? What is the purpose of this circuit?

Comment: +bat connected to Dummy DC Electronic Load of 100mA

Comment: Purpose of this circuit, I need to check whether that 47uF can support the voltage at +BAT for 100us, if the input voltage goes to 0V for 100us. So, using a MOSFET with FG, to simulate this behaviour and check whether the 47uF can support

Comment: Wouldn't be more convenient to just calculate what you are trying to achieve, meaning, how much voltage drop the Vbat will experience in case of a supply interruption: V_bat_final = sqrt( (11V - 0.6V  )^2 - 100mA * 100us * 2 / 47uF ) ~ 10.37V where 0.6V is approx. the forward voltage of the diode DO102.

Comment: Yes. Could you please tell me how you got this formula : V_bat_final = sqrt( (11V - 0.6V )^2 - 100mA * 100us * 2 / 47uF ) ?

Comment: @vtolentino , could you please help me with the formula

Comment: I will write an answer, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Sure thanks. Please help me with the formula as well. And Please help me to understand - "Why the blue trace waveform (MOSFET source connected to the top of the two series capacitors) in the second screenshot, does not go to full 0V when it should actually go?"

Comment: Please correct your schematics to show the "Dummy DC Electronic Load of 100mA", and show the actual connections to the MOSFET (as shown the Source is connected directly to ground, and the FG input isn't making sense). Use the built-in schematic editor (Circuitlab) to draw it.

Comment: The title should be the question in brief. If one has to search for the question in the description, then he may simply skip this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when the gate turns off and the source goes high impedance, you've got a **47uF capacitor** and a **100mA current sink** as the load. We can ignore the left half of the circuit because the capacitances are so small in comparison.

Over the 100us drop-out the load will draw out 100us*0.1A = 10uC of charge from the capacitor. Since capacitance is charge/voltage this will lower the voltage by 10uC/47uF = 0.21V. From the oscilloscope picture we see the voltage actually lowers by 0.72V. This could be explained by the capacitor having lower capacitance than it says, or more likely, the that the load draws more current than expected in these conditions, but we're in the right ballpark so I think this is the explanation.

**Edit to address the clarifying comments:**

If the source was actually a direct connection to GND when the gate is LOW, then yeah even with the capacitor circuit the voltage at the source would go LOW pretty immediately after the gate going LOW. But if the source becomes a **high impedance** connection to GND then what we actually see makes sense.

If the source behaves like a connection to GND through a large resistor then the charge on the capacitors can't disappear immediately and we'll see the slow decrease in voltage that we do see. In my calculation I assumed the source would behave as if it had infinite resistance, and we could disregard it completely so the only current flowing would be the 100mA load, but the voltage drops more than my calculations predicted. I speculated why this might be, but didn't consider that the source has a finite resistance, so some current can flow through it and explain the quicker than expected voltage decrease.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I have taken sometime to go through the basics and some time to contemplate on your answer.  But my fundamental question is, without connecting to my circuit (which starts with the 2x 100nF capacitors) , the MOSFET behaves as a perfect switch. Like, while the GATE is OFF, Source also goes LOW. But even If I connect this MOSFET to my circuit, the same thing should happen right? I should get the same LOW voltage at the point before the reverse protection diode, right? Why is it only going low for 0.72V?

Comment: I think you might have mistaken the blue trace in the second waveform. The blue trace in the second waveform is taken at the top of the 2x 100nF capacitors

Comment: I edited my answer and added a bit that hopefully answers your fundamental question better. To summarize it, I didn't mistake the traces, and when you connect the capacitor circuit with the MOSFET the same thing does not have to happen. The source does not become a 0 Ohm connection to GND so the capacitor charge takes time to disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Bsed on waveforms, we think that the source resistance is some big finite value or there is actually a source resistance present in my actual circuit which I have not mentioned in the answer. Correct? Before I accept your answer, please tell me. You have understood the purpose of my circuit which is to provide a 100us power interruption. So, for this purpose, I should make sure the source of the MOSFET is directly connected to the ground without any finite impedance to the ground so that the gate waveform is reflected at the source terminal also. Correct?

Comment: If possible, could you please modify my circuit with the MOSFET to mimic the 100us input power interruption?

Comment: You're correct on the first point, on the second point it depends on the kind of power interruption, but you may well be correct. If a low resistance connection to ground best mimics the kind of power interruption you want, then I would suggest using a half bridge - basically a PMOS connected to VCC together with an NMOS connected to GND, and when one is conducting the other is not so the load can be pulled both HIGH and LOW.

Comment: The third circuit [here](http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridge_drivers/) is a half bridge.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you connect the MOSFET to the load circuit try adding a 220 or 470 ohm resistor across C101/C102. In other words put the resistor from MOSFET source to GND. Then observe the difference in the switching waveform.

Comment: But why am I getting this waveform ? What might be the reason

Comment: The capacitors are holding the voltage up. If you tried the experiment that I suggested you should be able to see the caps discharge faster.

Comment: Also note that with your use of an NFET as a high side switch you will need to make sure the gate voltage swings from 11V to GND. A 5V gate transition will not cut the mustard.

Comment: Ok I will try the experiment. But two questions. 1. Does the 2 nF capacitors have the ability to hold up the voltage? Aren't they small to hold the charge for that time. And why does the gate of the MOSFET need to swing from 11V to 0V. It's just a switch right. If you give 5V , it will turn fully ON and if you give 0V, it goes fully OFF. Does the amplitude of the gate voltage swing really matter?

Comment: Added the MOSFET circuit and included the part number. Edited the question

Comment: The MOSFET is controlled by the voltage between gate and source.  The voltage between the gate and some distant point you choose to call Zero Volts is irrelevant.  Your drawing with thte MOSFET shows the source grounded, so that circuit won't work at all.

Comment: @Newbie - `why does the gate...need to swing...? It's just a switch...5V...turns fully ON...0V...(turns) fully OFF` -- This is a classic "newbie" misconception. All transistors -- NPN, PNP, N-channel MOSFET, P-channel MOSFETs, etc. -- only turn on when the voltage/current between the "switch" (base or gate) and the "output end" (emitter or source) exceeds some turn-on value. If the voltage at the output can change, then the voltage at the switch ***must also change*** to stay at/above this turn-on threshold. If Vgs-on is 5V, and the source rises to K volts, the gate must be at least K+5 volts.

Answer (score 0):

Your first circuit makes no sense.  (sorry to be harsh)  As (hand) drawn, the only thing that the Nfet can do is to short 11V to ground.  The rest of the circuit won't matter, ground is ground.  From your waveforms I expect that the fet is actually a P channel mosfet and is not connected to ground.
(going out on  a limb here)  Are you trying to charge the battery?  If so, you should really either add an inductor to the charging path and a free-wheeling diode, or put the battery in a large bucket of sand so when it catches fire from the peak current loads the fire will be mitigated.
[image: rudimentary charging circuit]

...and the series caps are near-useless.  Again,out on a limb as this smells like a battery charger.

Comment: afterthought, if you do have a Nmos fet, your gate drive will need to be referenced above the battery voltage, so unless you can make a 20V gate drive, I still think it's a P Channel device, (or at least should be).  Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry for the poor drawing and description of my circuit. The purpose of my circuit is to provide a 100us power interruption and check whether my output capacitor of 47uF could maintain the required threshold during that momentary power interruption. If my circuit is a PMOS, judging by my captured waveforms, there should a resistor between the source and the ground, right? Without the resistance between the source and the ground, I would not be getting this waveform, right

Comment: And also curious to understand the working of the battery charging circuit which you have designed. Could you please explain that too.

Comment: This circuit is a non-synchronous buck converter, the switch (mosfet) is intended to be opened and closed at a fixed frequency and a varying dtuy cycle to account for varying load.  For your circuit just get rid of the ground connection related to the mosfet all together.  I don't think it is there, if it were then your waveforms would not leave ground and you would roast your mosfet the first time you turned it on.  (V×V/Rdson=quick death for the mosfet)

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside for the moment your circuit, which should either use a P-MOSFET as a switch or a higher driver voltage for the N-MOSFET, based on your question and comments (and as requested), what you are really interested in, is to determine how long your pre-charged output capacitor can hold its voltage during a voltage interruption (e.g. 100us).

$$V_{CAP,final} = V_{CAP,initial} - \frac{I_{load}\cdot t}{C_{out}}$$

Where:

$$V_{CAP,initial} \approx V_{supply} - V_{Diode}$$

Plugging some values:

$$V_{CAP,final} = (11V - 0.5V) - \frac{100mA\cdot 100\mu s }{47\mu F}=10.287V$$

After this power shortage, the capacitor is then recharged to 10.5V again.

P.S. The formula in my comment assumed erroneously a load with constant power consumption, which is not your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer with calculation. Helped me to understand it better.

Comment: No problems. Let me know if I can help with something else.

Comment: Thank you. And as you have understood the purpose of my circuit, I should not connect the source resistance to ground so as to get a 0V at the source also, right? If I have a finite resistance between the source and the ground, my source terminal will hold some voltage and I will never get that voltage at that terminal to 0V, right? Only If I get the 0V at the source terminal, I would be able to mimic the 100us 0V power interruption. Am I correct? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Or could you please modify my circuit with MOSFET to mimic the 100us input power interruption, please.

Comment: Better if we join a chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105874/capacitor-discharge